# Можно ли заменить текст в бинарном файле PDF средствами Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Ничего похожего или рабочего не нашёл.
Имеются PDf файлы, в содержимом которых встречается дата в формате dd.mm.YYYY
Если способ автоматизировать задачу используя Python?

Comment: можно поверх нарисовать

Comment: ))))))))))))))))

Comment: Есть библиотека для работы с PDF форматом. гуглите считываете файл меняете что нужно и обратно преобразовываете.

Comment: pip install PyPDF2

Comment: Читайте документацию и вперёд, потом расскажете если получилось, и код покажете что получилось)

Comment: @Александр долго копал в сторону вашего совета. Но тут столкнулся с такой проблемой, те типы PDF файлов которые у меня, ни в какую не обрабатываются способами этой библиотеки. Вывода текста нет, она его не видит. Хотя пробовал на других PDF всё ок. Вручную эти фалы редактирую через Foxit Advanced PDF Editor, он не ругается, файлы редактируются штатно. Что ещё может подскажите?

Comment: Я если честно то же попробовал и PyPdf2 не прочёл ни одного файла PDF  будь он маленький или большой. Попробуйте  PDFMiner сначала считываете потом заново создаёте ну или доки почитайте ....